# SparkR MLlib & spark.ml: least squares and glm optimization

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, sparkr

Would anyone be able to explain how to specify optimization methods in the SparkR operation `glm`? When I try to fit an OLS model with `glm`, I can only specify `"normal"` or `"auto"` as the solver type. SparkR isn't able to interpret the solver specification `"l-bfgs"`, leading me to believe that when I do specify `"auto"`, SparkR simply assumes `"normal`" and then estimates the model coefficients analytically, using the LS normal equation.

Is fitting GLMs with stochastic gradient descent and L-BFGS not available in SparkR, or am I writing the following evaluation incorrectly?

```
m <- SparkR::glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, solver = "l-bfgs")
```

There's plenty of documentation in Spark about using iterative methods to fit GLMs, e.g. `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` and `LinearRegressionWithSGD` (discussed [here](http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html)), but I haven't been able to find any such documentation for the R API. Is this simply not available in SparkR (i.e. are SparkR users constrained to solving analytically and, therefore, constrained in the size of our data), or am I missing something essential here? If it isn't currently available in SparkR, is it supposed to come out with SparkR 2.0.0?

Below, I create a toy data set and fit three models, each with a different solver specification:

```
x1 <- rnorm(n=200, mean=10, sd=2)
x2 <- rnorm(n=200, mean=17, sd=3)
x3 <- rnorm(n=200, mean=8, sd=1)
y <- 1 + .2 * x1 + .4 * x2 + .5 * x3 + rnorm(n=200, mean=0, sd=.1)
dat <- cbind.data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

df <- as.DataFrame(sqlContext, dat)

m1 <- SparkR::glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, solver = "normal")
m2 <- SparkR::glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, solver = "auto")
m3 <- SparkR::glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, solver = "l-bfgs")
```

The first and second model result in the same parameter estimation values (supporting my assumption that SparkR is solving the normal equation when fitting both models and, consequently, the models are equivalent). SparkR is able to fit the third model, but when I try to print a summary of the GLM, I receive the following error:

[image: summary(m3) error]

For reference, I am doing this through AWS and have tried different versions of EMR, including the most recent (in case that makes a difference). Also, I am using Spark 1.6.1 (R API).

Comment: Which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: @eliasah, I've updated my post with the version of Spark that I am using. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

[Spark 1.6.2 API documentation is here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html)

> solver:
>   The solver algorithm used for optimization, this can be "l-bfgs", "normal" and "auto". "l-bfgs" denotes Limited-memory BFGS which is a limited-memory quasi-Newton optimization method. "normal" denotes using Normal Equation as an analytical solution to the linear regression problem. The default value is "auto" which means that the solver algorithm is selected automatically.

To me - this looks worthy of a bug report on the [Apache Spark Jira site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel).

Comment: Hi @SpiritusPrana, thanks for your comment. I know what each of the respective solvers do (saving auto, which is definitionally obscured), but you're saying that you think that I need to post to the SparkR Jira board, bringing this up as an issue?

Comment: before you open an issue please, can you update your question with what spark version have you tried this ? So we can reproduce the error

Comment: Hi @kathystehl - yes - your code looks well-formed to me, and consistent with the API documentation.  As it does not behave consistently it's worthy of research as a bug.  Probably worth waiting a little while to see if Eliasah comes back with advice.  As an R user with no experience of Apache projects I was a little daunted with logging SparkR bugs, but I have found the developers to be supportive and open to clearly worded bug reports.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SpiritusPrana! Yes, I agree. Also, Spark 2.0.0 is (hopefully) coming out soon, so perhaps my issue will be resolved once I move to the newest version.

Comment: The only way afaik to use a bfgs solver for glm is by using `optim()` which is not called anywhere in SparkR.